# The sum of power series with denominators $n!(n+1)!$

Tags: power-series, exponential-function, factorial

Regards.. I would like to discuss about the convergence function of the series
$$ \sum_{0}^{\infty} \: \frac{x^{n}}{n!(n+1)!}$$
If i write this series as function $f(x)$ and then integrate it, i would get :
$$ F(x) =\sum_{0}^{\infty} \: \frac{x^{n+1}}{((n+1)!)^{2}} $$
But, i have not found any explicit function for this series.

I may try that the function $f(x)$ must be of the form $ f(x) = g(x) e^{x} $. Then writing $g(x)$ and $e^{x}$ as power series :

\begin{align*} f(x) &= \sum_{0}^{\infty} \: \frac{x^{n}}{n!(n+1)!} \\
f(x) &= \left( a_{0} + a_{1}x + a_{2} x^{2} + ... \right) \times (1 + x + \frac{x^{2} }{2!} + \frac{x^{3}}{3!} + ... ) \end{align*}

Then, for few terms, $x$ and $x^{2}$ coefficients are : $ (a_{0} + a_{1}) = \frac{1}{1!2!}$,
$ (a_{0} + a_{1} + \frac{a_{2}}{2}) = \frac{1}{2!3!}$. The result is $a_{2} = -5/6 $.

If I may have some analysis of this, but **may not be the full answer**, direction is better. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to the [modified Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions) $$I_\alpha(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x/2)^{2n+\alpha}}{n!\, \Gamma(n+\alpha+1)}.$$
More precisely, we can write the power series you're looking for as
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!\,(n+1)!} = \frac1{\sqrt x} I_1(2\sqrt{x}).$$ So in particular there's no closed form in terms of elementary functions, but there are some nice differential equations and such.

Comment: Regards, Misha.. thanks. So based on your answer, there is no exact form. You also mention differential equations, i was also trying to integrate the series, i was relating this series to probability distributions (sums of $N$ exponential identical distributed rand.variables, where $N$ is Poisson distributed) and would like to calculate the MGF.